# Should the [bukkit] and [spigot] tags really be on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel like the [bukkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) and [spigot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spigot) tags shouldn't be on Stack Overflow. It's probably too late to do anything about it now, but I want to get my word out. The Spigot forums are a place where there are so many more people who are experienced. They would receive high quality answers and most likely faster than on here just because it's a lot more active for Bukkit and Spigot development.

It's kind of like having a separate Stack Exchange site for Bukkit and Spigot development. It's already out there, but people decide to come to Stack Overflow to have their questions answered. Some people never have their questions answered, or I'm sure have to use bounties. Who knows if they even get answered then? Questions always get answered on Spigot. That's a fact.

There are even countless guides and a wiki on the Spigot website that answer half of these people's questions. If they were redirected to the Spigot website, they could see all this and advance in their projects faster.

Comment: How does off-site support make tags unsuitable for the site? Many languages, libraries, technologies and more have significant support platforms other than SO.

Comment: The tag descriptions point to official websites where users can find more resources. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Okay. Just know they won’t get near the amount of support on Stack Overflow

Comment: That's not our problem. We just offer the service and provide the tags. People can ask or not, but there's no reason to discourage or prevent them from doing so if they want to, even in tags where there may be stronger communities elsewhere.

Comment: As an example, people post game development questions on Stack Overflow. I defend their right to do so as programming questions are programming questions, but at the same time... I would really recommend finding a more suitable place for them. Game dev questions are notoriously hard to ask in a Stack Overflow compatible way, the time  spent trying to cram the question into a format that passes all the rules is better spent in a back & forth on some other service trying to root out where problems begin and how to solve them best.

Comment: Do you think they shouldn't exist on SO because there are other sites that focus on those topics, or because you think the tags aren't about programming things?

Comment: @TylerH Other sites are better for this and some of them aren't even about programming

Comment: @AnstonSorensen Those are two separate problems. Other sites existing is not an issue. Questions not about programming are off-topic regardless of what they are about or what tags they use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should the [bukkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) and [spigot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spigot) tags really be on Stack Overflow?

Yes.

From [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.*
You can't imagine how enthusiast those Game Developers are.

From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Help page:  *if your question generally covers a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*

We honestly don't care if there are other sites / places where you can also be served. Even within the SE network a question doesn't become off-topic on one-site because it is on-topic on another site. I don't see why that rule should be different for off-network knowledge bases.

Whether the askers are well served here on SO is a different question. That is not something we have to solve by discriminating Game Developers that happen to love Stack Overflow. They already have all the guidance they need to find greener pastures when needed.

Answer (score 3):

I admittedly know very little about either of those, but based on the tag descriptions they appear to unambiguously identify a specific programming topic. That being said, they don't really meet any of the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate), which are:

1. **Does it unambiguously describe identify the topic? Does it describe the content?** The tag descriptions seem pretty clear and specifically identify the topic.
2. **Is it on-topic?** Again, based on the tag descriptions, absolutely - they clearly identify a programming topic.
3. **Does the tag add any information to the post?** Again, yes. If I was interested in those particular technologies, it would help me to know that that's what the question was about.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** What other possible meaning is there (other than what the tag description says)?

The fact that we may not have experts in those particular topics, that people aren't posting enough answers to questions there, or that there's already a good source of support elsewhere are not reasons to burninate.

Also, according to the argument you present here, why not prevent people from posting questions on those topics at all? If all we do is remove the tag but continue to allow questions on the topic, we'd actually make the problems you describe even worse by making it harder for people who do answer that type of question on Stack Overflow to find the relevant questions. Also, on what basis would we do so, given that these questions are clearly [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

If people who are posting in those tags are indeed having poor experiences with the site for whatever reason, that's worth a separate discussion, but it's not a reason to remove the tag entirely.

Also: *It's kind of like having a separate Stack Exchange site for Bukkit and Spigot development.* Except that they *aren't* Stack Exchange sites. The fact that there are other sites available doesn't mean that we can't offer people another choice. For example, I've posted in MSDN forums and Xamarin forums before, but that doesn't mean that I think that we should remove all Microsoft-related tags from the site. Quite the opposite, in fact - I've had a significantly better experience asking C# questions here than I have with MSDN forums. Other discussion forums have things like thread hijacking and endless posts saying "me too!" or asking for further clarification that make it much harder to find the information I'm looking for.